# What means apt-get install -f

Tags: apt, software-installation

What means `apt-get install -f`

I've already checked `install --help` But there is no info about `-f` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say that you're new to linux, this answer will help you use the linux documentation to find your current answer and future answers.

1. You should run the `man` command on the actual command, in this case `apt-get`, not on the argument to that command `install`.
2. Once you are in the `man` page, you can perform a forward search for an indented line beginning with `-f` by using the key sequence `/^ *-f`. In this case, the first result is just an anomaly, so press `n` to jump to the next match, and you will see a description and short discussion of the `-f` option, ie. `--fix-broken`.

That should get you able to find answers to all kinds of other questions you may have in the future.

Comment: If you accept the answer, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: What's confusing here is that `-f` is accepted as option to `apt-get` even though it comes after the non-option argument `install`, and contrary to many other commands using the GNU getopt API even with  `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment. That part is not well documented.